# How to add a class of "active" to individual elements in a functional navigation component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

This is something quite simple but somehow resulted in a crazy rabbit hole.

This link shows what I want:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp

Nothing special, now the thing becomes hairy for me when the elements in the navbar are rendered from an array of objects (from the specs). The approach I am following is basically rendering a list of buttons, this list of buttons is the state, since supposedly when you update a state it triggers a re-render, then when a button is clicked it "sets" the active class to false on the entire array-state then activates it only for the clicked one. So far it works.

The problem is that the active class is rendered two steps behind. One for the moment when the class in the array-state's elements are set to false, the other when the clicked element gets updated.

As far as I understand useState and setState are queues, hence those are applied asynchronously on each render, in order to avoid that and get the renders to show the current state, useEffect is utilized.

Now the thing is that I am not sure how to apply useEffect in order to achieve the immediate render of the "active" class.

This is the code I have:

```
import { options } from 'somewhere...'

export default function SideMenu(props){

  let auxArr = []
  let targetName
  const [stateOptions, setStateOptions] = useState([...options])
  const [currentOption, SetCurrentOption] = useState({})

  function activeOption(e){

// this helps with event bubbling

    if (e.target.tagName == "P" || e.target.tagName == "SPAN"){
      targetName = e.target.parentElement.id
    } else if (e.target.tagName == "IMG"){
      targetName = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id
    } else {
      targetName = e.target.id
    }

// since the main state is an array of objects I am updating it
// in three steps, first the current object is "activated"
// then the main array-state gets "inactivated" to erase all
// the previous "active" classes, finally the activated object 
// replaces the corresponding inactive object in the main state.

    let targetElement = stateOptions.filter(e => e.id==targetName)[0]
    SetCurrentOption({
      id: targetElement.id,
      activity:true,
      img: targetElement.img,
      name: targetElement.name
    })

// first the "classes" are set to false, then the 
// "activated" object replaces the corresponding one
// in the main object, from here comes the two 
// steps delay. 

    auxArr = [...stateOptions]
    auxArr.forEach(e => e.activity=false)
    setStateOptions(auxArr)
    const newOptions = stateOptions.map(e =>
      e.id==currentOption.id ? currentOption : e
      )
    setStateOptions(newOptions)
    }

    return(
      <aside className={styles.sideDiv}>
        <nav>
          {stateOptions.map(({id, img, name, activity, link}) => {
            return(
                <button key={id} id={id} onClick={activeOption} className={activity?styles.active:""}>
                  <Image src={img}/>
                  <p className={timeColor.theme}> {name} </p>
                </button>
            )
          })}
        </nav>
    </aside>
  )
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: where is active class?

Comment: You can use `useEffect` without dependency array if you wish to render the component on each state change. or if you wish to render the component on state changes for specific parts of state, then you need to pass those properties of the state, on which you wish to re-render. if you will provide empty dependency array, it will render the component only once.

Comment: An example to see how useEffect works : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-st4vcj

Comment: Hi @Majid, thanks for your help,  may you please provide an example relevant to this context.